# jquery append text if doesnot exists

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append text if it does not exists inside a form , if it exists donot append:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="horizontal-form">
<fieldset>
<input type="file" align="left" name="patient_image[]" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="6"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
jQuery(function(){


$('form').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('fieldset').html() ===  '<br/>Total image size is limited to 4MB.  If you are uploading more than one image, the total combined size is still 4MB.  Files should be formatted into JPG or BMP.') {
       $("input[name*='patient_image']").after('<br/>Total image size is limited to 4MB.  If you are uploading more than one image, the total combined size is still 4MB.  Files should be formatted into JPG or BMP.');
    }
});



});
```

Here is the link to fiddle I have tried so far: http://jsfiddle.net/zbpv5zfk/37/

Comment: Please post your Javascript in the actual question statement as well please.

Comment: You are doing it in wrong way. Fieldset text is not what you need. Add a div with a class, check is that class is exists in fieldset. If not, then add it with your text.

Comment: @lolka_bolka I cannot add class to it, just need to append as is

Comment: I can not understand what you're trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var sText = 'Total image size is limited to 4MB.  If you are uploading more than one image, the total combined size is still 4MB.  Files should be formatted into JPG or BMP.';
  $('form').find('fieldset:not(:contains("' + sText + '"))')
  .find("input[name*='patient_image']").after( '<br/>' + sText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="" class="horizontal-form">
  <fieldset>
    <input type="file" align="left" name="patient_image[]" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="6" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zbpv5zfk/40/ I tried adding if already existing content its adding double, need to add if there is not and if its already there not need.

Comment: Check out the modified code in my answer and this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/zbpv5zfk/43/ It should be fine now. Basically you cannot do a `:contains()` on an element -- `br` -- but you can do a `:has()` which we don't need to as the text is more identifying than `br`.

Answer (score 0):

It will never happens, because if you dump to the console this: `$(this).find('fieldset').html()` the valu of that will be:

`

```
                    <input name="patient_image[]" multiple="multiple" min="1" max="6" align="left" type="file">
             [and a new line and a lot of space here]
```

So, what you need is to do is check a part of your text, is there are, and append if not:

```
$(function() {
    if ($(this).find('fieldset').html().indexOf('Total image size is limited to 4MB') === -1) {
        $(this).find('fieldset').after('<br/>Total image size is limited to 4MB.  If you are uploading more than one image, the total combined size is still 4MB.  Files should be formatted into JPG or BMP.');
    }
});
```

See working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zbpv5zfk/38/

Of course you can use your whole string also. But i think, this is a bad practice, because if you want to change anything in your text, that is hard to maintain.